# Bootstrap 4 multilevel dropdowns are slightly misaligned

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap

I have been working with [this Bootstrap 4 snippet](https://bootsnipp.com/snippets/35p8X).

I have adjusted it slightly (so far) but am experiencing a slight drop on each of the subsequent dropdowns.

[image]

Here is the css as it stands:

```
    .menu-area {
    background: #d61a5e
}

.mainmenu ul li {
    position: relative;
}

.mainmenu .dropdown-menu {
    margin: 0;
    border-radius: 0;
}

.mainmenu a, .navbar-default .navbar-nav > li > a, .mainmenu ul li a, .navbar-expand-lg .navbar-nav .nav-link {
    color: #aaa;
    font-size: 16px;
    text-transform: capitalize;
    padding: 16px 15px;
    font-family: "Helvetica Neue", Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;
    display: block !important;
}


.mainmenu .active {
    color: #fff;
    background: #222;
}


/******************************Drop-down menu work on hover**********************************/
.mainmenu {
    background: none;
    border: 0 solid;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    min-height: 15px;
    width: 100%;
}

@media only screen and (min-width: 767px) {
    .mainmenu .collapse ul li:hover > ul {
        display: block;
    }

    .mainmenu .collapse ul ul {
        position: absolute;
        top: 100%;
        left: 0;
        min-width: 250px;
        display: none;
    }
    /*******/
    .mainmenu .collapse ul ul li {
        position: relative
    }

    .mainmenu .collapse ul ul li:hover > ul {
        display: block
    }

    .mainmenu .collapse ul ul ul {
        position: absolute;
        top: 0;
        left: 100%;
        min-width: 250px;
        display: none
    }
    /*******/
    .mainmenu .collapse ul ul ul li {
        position: relative
    }

    .mainmenu .collapse ul ul ul li:hover ul {
        display: block
    }

    .mainmenu .collapse ul ul ul ul {
        position: absolute;
        top: 0;
        left: 100%;
        min-width: 250px;
        display: none;
        z-index: 1
    }
}

@media only screen and (max-width: 767px) {
    .navbar-nav .show .dropdown-menu .dropdown-menu > li > a {
        padding: 16px 15px 16px 35px
    }

    .navbar-nav .show .dropdown-menu .dropdown-menu .dropdown-menu > li > a {
        padding: 16px 15px 16px 45px
    }
}
```

Having followed the snippet I am not that sure as to why each level is slightly lower than the last. I think its to do with the hover section of the css but I do not know how to adjust this to force it to level up..

I am hoping someone might know how to fix this.

**EDIT**
Here is the Html for the page.

The thing about Aurelia is that it tries to get out of the way of javascript which might help with those that know JS well.

```
    <template>
    <require from="./navmenu.scss"></require>
    <require from="./activeRoute"></require>
    <nav class="navbar navbar-expand-lg navbar-dark bg-dark mainmenu mr-auto">
        <a class="navbar-brand" href="#/home">JobsLedger</a>
        <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbarSupportedContent" aria-controls="navbarSupportedContent" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
            <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
        </button>

        <div class="navbar-collapse collapse" id="navbarSupportedContent">
            <ul class="navbar-nav mr-auto">
                <li repeat.for="route of router.navigation">
                    <a href.bind="route.href" if.bind="!route.settings.nav" class=" ${route.href == topUrl ? 'active' : ''}">
                        ${route.title}
                    </a>
                    <a href.bind="route.href" if.bind="route.settings.nav" class="dropdown-toggle ${route.href == topUrl ? 'active' : ''}" href="#" id="navbarDropdown" role="button" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">
                        ${route.title}
                    </a>

                    <ul if.bind="route.settings.nav" class="dropdown-menu" aria-labelledby="navbarDropdown">
                        <li repeat.for="menu of route.settings.nav">
                            <a href.bind="menu.href" if.bind="!menu.settings.nav" class="dropdown-menu-link">
                                ${menu.title}
                            </a>
                            <a href.bind="menu.href" if.bind="menu.settings.nav" class="dropdown-toggle dropdown-menu-toggle" href="#" id="navbarDropdown" role="button" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">
                                ${menu.title} <span class="caret-right"></span>
                            </a>

                            <ul if.bind="menu.settings.nav" class="dropdown-menu" aria-labelledby="navbarDropdown">
                                <li repeat.for="subMenu of menu.settings.nav">
                                    <a href.bind="subMenu.href" if.bind="!subMenu.settings.nav" class="dropdown-menu-link">
                                        ${subMenu.title}
                                    </a>
                                    <a href.bind="subMenu.href" if.bind="subMenu.settings.nav" class="dropdown-toggle dropdown-subMenu-toggle" href="#" id="navbarDropdown" role="button" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">
                                        ${subMenu.title} <span class="caret-right"></span>
                                    </a>

                                    <ul if.bind="subMenu.settings.nav" class="dropdown-menu" aria-labelledby="navbarDropdown">
                                        <li repeat.for="lowestSubMenu of subMenu.settings.nav">
                                            <a href.bind="lowestSubMenu.href" if.bind="!lowestSubMenu.settings.divider" class="dropdown-menu-link">
                                                ${lowestSubMenu.title}
                                            </a>
                                        </li>
                                    </ul>

                                </li>

                            </ul>

                        </li>

                    </ul>

                </li>

            </ul>


            <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right mr-auto">
                <li repeat.for="route of router.navigation" if.bind="route.settings.pos == 'right'" class="${ row.isActive ? 'link-active' : '' }">
                    <a href.bind="route.href" if.bind="!row.settings.nav">${ row.title }</a>

                    <a href.bind="route.href" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" role="button" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false"
                         if.bind="route.settings.nav">
                        ${row.title}
                        <span class="caret"></span>
                    </a>

                    <ul if.bind="route.settings.nav" class="dropdown-menu">
                        <li repeat.for="menu of row.settings.nav">
                            <a href.bind="menu.href">${menu.title}</a>
                        </li>
                    </ul>
                </li>
                <li><a>Welcome ${userName}</a></li>
                <li><a href="#" click.delegate="logout()">Log Out</a></li>
            </ul>
        </div>
    </nav>
</template>
```

Comment: Is it possible that you have some globally set styles, in you **styles.css**, that are affecting the behavior of your snippet ?

Comment: can you add your html and css here

Comment: Can you create a snippet or a fiddle/similar that we can take a look at? It will help us with your issue.

Comment: Its absolutely possible that there are global styles. The project is an Aurelia SPA with ASP.Net Core 3.0.  Re the html I shall add that now. Re the fiddle plunket etc.. not sure how to do that as this stage although it would be great to get that going..

Comment: OK so I have found something.. went through all the styles on the right side and slowly unclicked each style until I found one that changed it.. it was dulled out but not crossed out. Padding: 0.5em; Added padding: 0; and this has dragged it much much closer. It seems to be a line out now.